# Why quill can't find driverClassName and jdbcUrl using IDEA?

Tags: scala, quill

I try to learn quill,as the doc said:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.28.0",
"io.getquill" %% "quill-jdbc" % "3.7.0"
//"io.getquill" %% "quill-jdbc" % "3.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

sqlite or mysql both use library quill-jdbc

then write this:

```
ctx.driverClassName=org.sqlite.JDBC
ctx.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/db/file.db
```

IDEA told me "can't resolve symbol driverClassName" and "can't resolve symbol jdbcUrl"

I don't know why,should I use sbt directly instend using IDEA?I think I will got the same error

so what should I do?Thanks!

Comment: Did you put the config into `application.properties` as the quill readme says, or into build.sbt / some random source file?

Comment: I have,but got error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load data source for config: 'Config(SimpleConfigObject({}))'

Comment: Can you share your Scala code where you initialize quill?